# What is LE (plant contents)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry

I am reading the contents of the oatstraw:

> .. high in vitamins A, C, B complex, LE, G..

I am unable to find on the Internet what LE refers to.

Comment: What brand is this?  It could be a way the company notates a particular chemical.

Comment: No idea, I just have access to the list of ingredients and unfortunately no more information. I have started thinking if they have missed the comma "," between L and E. Is there a vitamin L? Never heard of L.

Comment: "Vitamin L": http://micro.magnet.fsu.edu/vitamins/pages/anthranilic.html

Comment: No problem; that being said I have no clue what LE is supposed to be... Seems a bit odd to have a missing both a comma and a space in a nutrient facts sheet.

Answer (score 1):

My answer will unfortunately have almost nothing to do with chemistry.

The quoted statement is BS, there's no vitamin LE.

This claim appears to appear on several web pages, the common source seems to be a post from an nutrition/herbal oriented mailing list from 1998:<sup>[1]</sup>

> …
>
> OATSTRAW
> Oatstraw as any livestock breeder will confirm, builds the strongest possible
> body, with the greatest resilience. Used extensively in European cultures
> throughout time for health and beauty, our country has let this valuable herb
> slide into disuse.
> Contains: calcium. high in Vitamins A, C, B complex, LE, G, phosphorus,
> potassium, proteins.
> Oatstraw contains Avenin, an amorphous alkaloid which is highly nutritive to
> cells, improving normal cellular reproduction.
>
> …

*(also note e.g. that avenin is not an alkaloid but protein)*

I have an evolution theory how the author could have made this typo, when (hopefully) compiling a literature:

> … vitamins A, B complex, C, E, …
>
> … vitamins A, B complex, C E, …
>
> … vitamins A, B complex, CE, …
>
> … vitamins A, B complex, LE, …
>
> … vitamins A, C, B complex, LE, …

(Some intermediate forms might be purely hypothetical. An intermediate form *“… vitamins A, B complex, C E, …”* can be seen alive at the page mentioning oatstraw, at a different product though<sup>[2]</sup>)

References:

1. http://www.geocities.ws/chdigest/herbs/pages/apr1998
2. https://www.healthylife-solutions.com/blog/2017/5/15/womens-herbal-tea-recipe

Comment: That's indeed quite plausible and may serve a great illustration to why choosing a good typeface is important (also, congrats on 4000 rep. :) ).